# switching numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I have N-time steps and want to create N  real numbers  corresponding to each time step as follows:  the numbers should be in the range [a, b] with a switching probability of p. 
Ie, if kth number (corresponding to kth time step) is n, then the probability that k+1th number (corresponding to k+1th time step) is any other number different than n is p.  All created numbers should be in the range [a,b].

How can this be done in matlab? 
Thanks.

Comment: I am, admittedly, speculating, but, if you are interested in simulating a finite Markov chain, the way you pose the problem will confuse people.

Comment: no. my objective is just as the one posed above.

Comment: @user3489173 the question is not very clear, please edit

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Is your problem generating random numbers in `[a, b]` or generating number `k+1` given number `k`?

Comment: I did not try anything so far. The objective is to create a sequence of N numbers from scratch.

Comment: @user3489173: It's frowned-upon to post a question on Stack Overflow without actually putting some effort in first.  Please make an attempt yourself, and then post a question when you actually get stuck.

Comment: @user3489173: thanks for your advice but i am not looking for an advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure that I got all of your requirements but this might be the script you are searching for:

```
N = 10;     % count of numbers
p = 0.2;    % switching probability
a = 5;
b = 20; 

% init empty numbers and get the first random number
numbers = zeros(N,1);
numbers(1) = rand(1) * (b-a) + a;

for iNumber = 2:N
    % test if number must change
    if rand(1) < (1-p)
        % the number must be the same than the previous
        % copy the value and go to next number
        numbers(iNumber) = numbers(iNumber-1);
        continue;

    else 
        % a new number must be found
        while 1
            % get a new random number 
            numbers(iNumber) = rand(1) * (b-a) + a;

            % check if the new random number is different from the previous
            if numbers(iNumber) ~= numbers(iNumber-1)
                % in case they are different, the while 1 can be stopped
                break;
            end

        end % while 1

    end % if rand(1) < (1-p)
end % for iNumber = 2:N
```

Comment: it seems okay. thanks infinitely many times...

Answer (score 0):

Guaranteed super random:

```
N = randi(100);
p = rand;
l1 = rand*randi(100);
l2 = rand*randi(100);

if l2 < l1
  [l2 l1] = deal(l1,l2);
end

out = []

while isempty(out)
    if rand>rand
        n = 2:N
        a = rand([N,1])*(l2-l1)+l1;
        x = rand([N-1,1])<p;
        n(x==0)=n(x==0)-1;
        n = [1 n];
        out = a(n);
    end
end
```